# Google Sheets - Formula for conditional formatting - If any 2+ Columns contain the same date turn another cell blue (Same date in calendar)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a calendar that I need to label with a different colour if there are two events happening on the same day.

I have tried - `=match(B5,$L:$L, 0) * match(B5,$P:$P, 0)*match(B5,$T:$T, 0)` which will work if all 3 columns contain the same date, but I need this to work if any 2+ columns contain the same date (8 total columns exist)

Any help is appreciated!

The main aim is to create a calendar that shows the events in different cities - I have begun displaying things like this as a workaround for if 2 events are on the same date, it would only be colour coded based on the first conditional formatting statement (and omit the second). If there is a better solution to just turning all multiple event dates a third colour I am all ears!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional format as on the screenshot

[image: example]